# Comma thousands separator in a column label disappears when using the `modify_header` function of the `gtsummary` package

Tags: r, gtsummary

When I use the `modify_header` function of the `gtsummary` package, the comma thousands separator in a column label disappears.

Is there a way to make the comma thousands separator appear again? Thanks in advance.

Bellow I provide a minimal example:

```
library(gtsummary)
library(tidyverse)
data(diamonds)

diamonds %>%
select(carat) %>% 
tbl_summary()
```

[image]

Using the `modify_header` function, the comma thousands separator disappears:

```
diamonds %>%
select(carat) %>% 
tbl_summary() %>%
modify_header(stat_0 = "**Number of diamonds = {N}**")
```

[image]

Comment: Untested because I don't have `gtsummary` installed but you could likely use `"**Number of diamonds = {prettyNum(N, big.mark = ',')}**"`.

Answer (score 0):

modify_header(label = "**X**", stat_1 = '**Y
N = {style_number(N)}**', stat_2 = '**Z
N = {style_number(N)}**')

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).